# Why do the links inside my dropdown menu not refer to other page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a new website and I came across a problem. All the content inside my dropdown button are not engaging. I have a link inside a [dropdown button in my footer](https://kraamzorgmama.webexact.nl) (on mobile), and it does not link to another page.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown left-float">
    <a class="drop" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block; border-radius:0px !important;">
        Sitemap
        <span class="pijl-rechts" style="float:right;">
            <img src="img/caret-right.png" />
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:relative; display:block; width:100%; margin-top:0px;">
        <li><a href="waarom-kraamzorg-mama">Kraamzorg Mama</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="mamapas">Mamapas</a></li>
        <li><a href="vacatures">Openstaande vacatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="algemene-voorwaardes"> Algemene voorwaardes (icoon slot) </a></li>
        <li><a href="disclamer">Disclaimer</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    /*Downloaded from https://www.codeseek.co/danmalarkey/dropdown-with-rotating-caret-DBrxG */
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
            $($(e.target).find('.pijl-rechts').toggleClass('open-caret'));
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(document).click(function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
                $('.pijl-rechts').removeClass('open-caret');
            });
        });
        
        
        $('.pijl-rechts').click(function(e) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
            $($(e.target).find('.pijl-rechts').toggleClass('open-caret'));
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(document).click(function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
                $('.pijl-rechts').removeClass('open-caret');
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Really not enough known about your site configuration or what actually happens when you click those links

Answer (score 0):

considering the contact, vacatures, etc links are directories, you need to add a / before the link. It can be fixed as such:

```
<div class="dropdown left-float">
<a class="drop" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block; border-radius:0px !important;">
    Sitemap
    <span class="pijl-rechts" style="float:right;">
        <img src="img/caret-right.png" />
    </span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:relative; display:block; width:100%; margin-top:0px;">
    <li><a href="/waarom-kraamzorg-mama">Kraamzorg Mama</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mamapas">Mamapas</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vacatures">Openstaande vacatures</a></li>
    <li><a href="/algemene-voorwaardes"> Algemene voorwaardes (icoon slot) </a></li>
    <li><a href="/disclamer">Disclaimer</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

If these links are supposed to redirect to html pages, it can be fixed by adding .html to the links. As such:

```
<div class="dropdown left-float">
<a class="drop" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block; border-radius:0px !important;">
    Sitemap
    <span class="pijl-rechts" style="float:right;">
        <img src="img/caret-right.png" />
    </span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:relative; display:block; width:100%; margin-top:0px;">
    <li><a href="waarom-kraamzorg-mama.html">Kraamzorg Mama</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="mamapas.html">Mamapas</a></li>
    <li><a href="vacatures.html">Openstaande vacatures</a></li>
    <li><a href="algemene-voorwaardes.html"> Algemene voorwaardes (icoon slot) </a></li>
    <li><a href="/disclamer">Disclaimer</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with the links. When I click on the link it closes the dropdown. But why does the dropdown close when I click on the content in it. That is the issue I am having right now...

Answer (score -1):

The href property on your anchor tags need to be paths to a file.
Examples href="pages/contact.html", href="https://www.example.com/contact"

It depends on your folder structure and where those files are located relative to the file you are currently viewing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Lots of cases where links do not point to an actual file or even a real directory

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I agree. However, in this case the link points to another page on the same site. What could that be besides another file?

Comment: @Bro3Simon actually, there is nothing wrong with the links. When I click on the link it closes the dropdown. But why does the dropdown close when I click on the content in it. That is the issue I am having right now